# Programmatically determine if Sagepay card details form is incomplete

Tags: opayo

I'm looking for some help with regards to the drop-in checkout integration.
https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo/integrate-our-drop-checkout

In particular I'm following ‘custom flow’ example - see first code example for the Custom Flow section. https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo/spec/api-reference#section/Custom-flow

In summary how can I programmatically determine if the sagepay 'card details' form which is injected into the sp-container (hosted in an iframe) is not valid for submission/tokenisation, when a call ‘tokenise’ link is used?
For example when the user has not completed all the required fields; Name, Card Number, Expiry or CVC.

I'm following the flow calling `sagepayCheckout.tokenise()` when the user clicks our 'Complete Payment' button (referred to as the tokenise link in the custom flow example).

NB: Implementation is part of a SPA app in my particular case I'm not submitting the (outer) form rather handling things using javascipt and calling the tokenise method.

Normally the `onTokenise` call back method is called on success or when wrong card details have been entered or merchantKey has expired. But when the injected sagepay form fails its own validity the `onTokenise` call back is never called.

NB: Due to browser security I can't check the state of the fields inside the iframe.

Ok some good points to note:

- The sagepay form does feedback to the user about errors that required fields need to be completed.
- And `sagepayCheckout.tokenise()` doesn't try to submit my (outer) form when these errors exist.
  But there doesn't seem to be a programmatic way to know if the required fields need to be complete (or the `onTokenise` call back wont be called).

The main reason I need to know when the form is incompleted or tokenise has failed would be to re-enable our 'Complete Payment' button. Currently our button is disabled as soon as the user clicks it to prevent multiple clicks.

Answer (score 2):

I am having this exact same problem. The only way I have been able to think of to get around this is to use the message event listener on the window. The sagepay.js library registers a 'message' event on the window object probably when the sagepayCheckout method is called.

Side note: this method is also poorly implemented as anything else that uses the window message event will cause the sagpay.js library to throw errors.

I think the only purpose of sagepay.js' message event hander is to resize the iframe window when its content changes. If you were to assume the content of the iframe will only change when validation fails you might be able use that to reset the state of your 'Complete Payment' button.

I would also suggest making a complaint to Opayo. This library is clunky and in desperate need of improvement.

Comment: Ok, its been a couple of months and didn't find a solution - I do remember contacting their support, who pretty much wanted to wash their hands of it, referring me back to the online documentation. To quote from the support response email; "Unfortunately we are not developers and this is not a service that we offer. All the integration and protocol guides are available to download from our website"

Comment: Went back through my notes & found my proposed solution (not yet released!) tldr; the proposed solution was to use a timeout! When calling the tokenise method, also start a timeout. If the timeout happens then assume the form validation in sagepay.js has failed. If the tokenise callback is called then 1st check if timeout has occurred, and if it has then don't continue/exit callback method. But if in the callback the timeout hasn't occurred, then cancel the timeout and continue making sure to check for a success result.

Comment: So the only problem with a timeout is when we have a slow network - I've used 5 seconds hoping this is enough time for the sagepay http validation call. Checking if timeout has occurred and existing early in the callback is important because the slow network problems - I didn't want to submit payment if user might have been able to click the submit button a 2nd time (ie once timeout occurred and before tokenise callback).

Comment: What I ended up doing was not disabling may pay button until I got a tokenise response back, and then I disabled it for the remaining payment flow. So the user could potentially send multiple tokenise requests by rapid clicking but I figured, I don't care if they get smashed with requests, as long as I get at least one response.

Comment: I think your approach makes more sense - problem I have is SagePay is just an implementation of a abstraction for a payment gateway. The other gateways include Stripe & WorldPay and their flows work different meaning the safe option is to disable the submit button straight away.